# error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currentpl' referenced before assignment:

Tags: python

The following code gives the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currentpl' referenced before assignment:

```
def play(num_sq, user_choice):
    drawStrip(num_sq)
    if user_choice == 0:
        currentpl = 1
    elif user_choice == 1:
        currentpl = 2
    while gameover(num_sq):
        if currentpl == 1:
            pick = getPlayerPick(num_sq)
            while not validPlay(pick, num_sq):
                pick = getPlayerPick(num_sq)
            makePlay(pick, player_col[currentpl])
        if currentpl == 2:
            pick = computerSelection(num_sq)
            makePlay(pick, player_col[currentpl])
        currentpl = togglePlayer(currentpl)
    if currentpl == 2:
        return "User"
    return "Computer"
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens when `user_choice` is not 0 or 1?

if `user_choice` isn't either 1 or 0 then netiher of the `currentpl = 1` or `currentpl=2` lines get executed. This means `currentpl` is 'unassigned' - it really doesnt exist. This causes issues when you reach a line like

```
if currentpl == 1:
```

because `currentpl` doesnt yet exist - it's unassigned.

This isnt allowed - you need to allow for situations where `user_choce` is not 0 or 1 by having something like:

```
else:
    currentpl=10
```

after your last `elif` clause.

An alternnative approach would be to make sure in the code that executes before this section that `user_choice` is ALWAYS either equal to 0 or equal to 1 in which case you could be sure that `currentpl` is assigned (exists) before you need to test its value.

Comment: Am sorry stewart, am kinda new to this and so i do not understand what you are saying

Comment: @deedee no worries - ive tried to clarfy my answer above

Comment: stewart can you rephrase the code with your suggestion please because its not working from my end

Comment: nevermind stewart, i fixed it, thank you for your help.....all i did was initialized it to 0 and then add 1 and 2